# Error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant in VC 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, dev-c++

```
char filename[256];
scanf("%s", filename);
FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

int M, N, C, i, j, P, G;

fscanf(file, "%d", &M); 
fscanf(file, "%d", &N); 
fscanf(file, "%d", &C);

int xv[M + 1], yv[M + 1], h[M + 1]; // line 21

for (i = 1; i <= M; i++) {
    fscanf(file, "%d", &xv[i]);
    fscanf(file, "%d", &yv[i]);
    fscanf(file, "%d", &h[i]);
}
```

Compiler VC 2017 return error:

> error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
>
> note: fault caused by a reading of a variable out of its lifetime
>
> note: see use of "%*"

Why this error appears in VS 2017 and when I use the Dev-C++ IDE it does not give an error and it executes correctly?

Comment: Instead of `int xv[M + 1], yv[M + 1], h[M + 1];` you should use `std::vector<int> xv(M + 1), yv(M + 1), h(M + 1);`.

Comment: *when I use the Dev-C++ IDE it does not give an error* -- Yet another victim of the `g++` variable-length array non-C++ syntax.  VS 2017 is correct in giving you the error.  That line of code is not C++.

Comment: It works in Dev-C++ because Dev-C++ uses MinGW, and MinGW uses gcc, and gcc [supports variable-length arrays as a nonstandard extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).